# Suppress section with condtion

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to suppress a section in Crystal Reports when the Change column is less than the absolute value of $12,000 AND if the Group By is Customer

How can I implement something like this below?

```
if abs({change}) < 12000 and {group by} = "Customer" then TRUE
```

Comment: What causes the Group By value to change? Is it a parameter? Or does it ever change?

Comment: We have created a Group By parameter to return Customer, Product, and Employee and we also have a Group By formula to return certain fields for each of the values of the parameter.

Comment: Perfect. You should be able to just reuse that formula.

Comment: Okay, so I believe that formula is right.. although, when i place it in the suppress formula area and save nothing happens to my data.  We have suppressed the group header 1 and details section and I was placing this information into the suppress section of the group footer 1.  The information goes through all of these sections because we used the sum function and added it to all group levels.. Is there something we could be missing, or just adding it to the wrong suppress section?

Comment: Which section holds the data? It's worth noting that by the time Crystal reaches your Group Header it will only calculate based on the first record for that group, and the Footer will only calculate based on the last record.

Comment: We placed the data into the details section

Comment: Based on your previous comment, this would suppress the Header and Details section all the time, and *only* suppress the group footer if the *last* record evaluated in that group has the correct Change value.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll never need to write something like `If XYZ then True` because you get the same result from just `XYZ`. So that will simplify your code a bit.

You have the correct code for checking absolute value, so your issue probably lies with checking the Group By value. The Group By value is whatever you set it to be, but it's always set to an existing table object or formula. This would transform your formula into this:

```
(ABS({change}) < 12000) AND ({@groupByFormula} = "Customer")
```